# Probability of order statistics with numerous conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y_i$ be the i-th order statistic of a continuous random variable $Y$ and let $z_{k-1}\leq z_k$ for all $k$. Let $1\leq j\leq n-1$. How can I evaluate or rewrite $$Pr(Y_{n-j-1}\leq z_{k-1}<Y_{n-j}\leq Y_{n-1}\leq z_k),$$ so the probability that $Y_{n-j-1}$ is smaller or equal than $z_{k-1}$ AND that $Y_{n-j}$ is larger than $z_{k-1}$ AND...

I would like to rewrite it in terms of probability distributions $F_{Y_i}$ of the $Y_i$, but the numerous inequalities confuse me. I know that $$Pr(A\cap B)  = Pr(A|B)P(B) = Pr(B|A)Pr(A),$$I'm not sure how to apply it here...

Comment: Can one assume $Y$ to be a _continuous_ random variable?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, forgot to add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${n\choose n-j-1}F(z_{k-1})^{n-j-1}{j+1\choose j}(F(z_k)-F(z_{k-1}))^j$$
**Deciphering the formula:**

- The first binomial factor is the number of ways of choosing  $n-j-1$ elements from the whole sample (the ones that will be below $z_{k-1}$).
- The first power of $F$ is the probability that these elements are indeed all below $z_{k-1}$.
- The second binomial factor is the number of ways of choosing $j$ elements from the remaining sample of size $j+1$ (the ones that will be between $z_{k-1}$ and $z_k$).
- The last factor involving $F$ is the probability that these elements are indeed all between $z_{k-1}$ and $z_k$.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind giving an explanation how you did it? You could also upload the handwritten notes, I would then TeX it and add it here.